# knockout - link 2 dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout-2.0

I am trying to populate one dropdown based on another, using knockout, and it doesn't go too well. The entire code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/UHQUX/3/, on my machine it generates the first 2 dropdowns, but the second one (that should be populated from Operators) is never filled in.
These are 2 dropdowns that are supposed to be linked:

```
    <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.ColumnNames, value: SearchCriteria(), optionsValue: 'ColumnName', optionsText: 'ColumnDisplayName', optionsCaption: '', attr: { 'id': 'Search_' +Id() + '__ColumnName', name: 'Search[' + Id() + '].ColumnName' }"></select></td>
    <td><select data-bind="options: Operators, optionsValue: 'OpId', optionsText: 'OpName'"></select></td>
```

This is the function that creates a new item :

```
 function SearchCriteriaItem(id, searchCriteria, links, operators) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable(id);
        self.SearchCriteria = ko.observable(searchCriteria);

        self.Operators = ko.computed(function() {
            if (self.SearchCriteria() !== null) {
                var opId;
                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    if (links[i].ColumnName == self.SearchCriteria()) {
                        opId = links[i].OpId;
                    }
                }
                var ops = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < operators.length; j++) {
                    if (operators[j].OpId == opId) {
                        op.push(operators[j]);
                    }
                }
                return ops;
            }
            return [];
        });
    }
```

And this is the model view:

```
function SearchCriteriaViewModel() {
var self = this;

var data = [];
var columnNames = [];
data.push({
    ColumnName: 'test1',
    ColumnDisplayName: 'Test 1',
    OpId: '1',
    ColumnValuesId: '1'
});
columnNames.push({
    ColumnName: 'test1',
    ColumnDisplayName: 'Test 1'
});
data.push({
    ColumnName: 'test2',
    ColumnDisplayName: 'Test 2',
    OpId: '2',
    ColumnValuesId: '2'
});
columnNames.push({
    ColumnName: 'test2',
    ColumnDisplayName: 'Test 2'
});
self.Links = data;
self.ColumnNames = columnNames;

var operators = [];
operators.push({
    OpId: '1',
    OpName: 'Test Op'
});

var searchCriteria = [];
self.AvailableSearchItems = searchCriteria;
self.Search = ko.observableArray();

for (var i = 0; i < self.AvailableSearchItems.length; i++) {
    var id = GenerateGuid();
    self.Search.push(new SearchCriteriaItem(id, self.AvailableSearchItems[i], self.Links, operators));
}

self.addSearchCriteria = function () {
    id = GenerateGuid();
    self.Search.push(new SearchCriteriaItem(id, self.AvailableSearchItems[0], self.Links, operators));
};
```

}

Also, the id is always the same, no matter how many Search Criteria I add. The id is generated by an ajax call to the controller which returns a new GUID. The values returned are different but the html shows the same id for all rows...

Update: I updated the code to make more sense: http://jsfiddle.net/UHQUX/4/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is incorrect. `self.AvailableSearchItems` is always `[]`, and `self.AvailableSearchItems[0]` is always `undefined`

Comment: You are right, self.AvailableSearchItems is always empty for now, it is supposed to be populated from the MVC model, in case some search criteria are already in the model. Anyway, the code works up to  a point, I get the columnNames in the first drop down, and if I set the first dropdown like this: "<td><select data-bind="options: $parent.ColumnNames, value: SearchCriteria, optionsValue:..." the second dropdown gets populated also when I change the value in the first. But setting it like this is wrong, because in case of multiple search criteria, all dropdowns change when I change one...

Comment: I think I fixed that problem by creating nested arrays, but now I have another one: the dropdowns don't have a value selected if I send a value initially. Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/aUbtT/